# So I am learning Python 3.x and the book want to use a loop that prints a list. but

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

So I am learning Python 3.x and the book want to use a loop that prints a list.

basically it has three items in the list and, assigns them into a variable and then prints the last item in the new variable...so it looks something like this:

```
for magician in magicians:
    print(magicians)
```

however when I do this it tells me that the second variable is not defined.

but if I do this it works fine:

```
for magicians in magicians:
    print(magicians)
```

Is the book wrong or am I do something wrong? any insight would be awesome!

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: you want to print `magician` instead of `magicians` in your first example. in the second example you are redefining the thing you are looping over, which is rarely a good idea. Also, in both examples the indentation is incorrect, and in the second example a colon is missing, rendering all code inexecutalbe.

Comment: Also, indents are required. In the next line after a colon, indent that line by one tab

Comment: Note that both code blocks have at least one ``SyntaxError``. They will not work at all. Please [edit] your question to include a [mvce].

Comment: @warped yup that was the problem, good catch. If you put that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup I indented in my program, just couldn't figure out how to do it on here.

Comment: You just add more spaces in front of the lines that need to be indented!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First example:

```
for magician in magicians:
    print(magician)

# print(magicians) would print the entire thing you are looping over.
```

Second example:

by doing

```
for magicians in magicians:
    [...]
```

you redefine the thing you are looping over.

That said, your code is incorrectly indented, and in the first version of the post a colon was missing, so the code, in the way you showed it would not compute, and would not print anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way:

```
magicians = ['m1', 'm2']

for magician in magicians:
    print(magician)
```